# Why is mapcar only using one of the arguments returned from values-list?

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, map-function

I'm pretty new to Lisp and I have the following problem.

I'm trying to swap the numbers around in multiple lists and produce a list of lists as the result, so that all the numbers that were the 1st number in each list will all be collected in a list which is the 1st element of the result list; and all the numbers that were 2nd in each list will be collected in another list which is the 2nd element of the result list; and so on.

Here is an example:

```
(foo '((3 4 2 4) (2 5 6 9) (1 -2 8 10)) ) 
=> ((3 2 1) (4 5 -2) (2 6 8) (4 9 10))
```

My current solution is this:

```
(defun foo (list)
    (mapcar #'list (values-list list))
)
```

As far as I understand it, `values-list` should return all sublists from inside the given parameter `list`. Then `mapcar` will go through each element of each sublist and make them into a list.

This second part works, however what happens is that only the first sublist is used, resulting in `((3) (4) (2) (4))` instead of `((3 2 1) (4 5 -2) (2 6 8) (4 9 10))`.

Why is this?

(I'm using CLISP).

Comment: search "values-list CLHS".

Comment: In this case the implementation does not make a difference, because the behavior you are asking about is well standardized across implementations.

Answer (score 3):

In your code

```
(defun foo (list)
  (mapcar #'list (values-list list)))
```

`values-list` returns the list as multiple values. But you are calling a function like `mapcar` and a normal function call takes only one value per argument.

To repair that, you could call `mapcar` via `multiple-value-call`:

```
CL-USER 47 > (defun foo (list)
               (multiple-value-call #'mapcar #'list (values-list list)))
FOO

CL-USER 48 > (foo '((3 4 2 4) (2 5 6 9) (1 -2 8 10)) )
((3 2 1) (4 5 -2) (2 6 8) (4 9 10))
```

Above then will pass all values to `mapcar`.

Note that argument lists are limited in Common Lisp implementations. See the variable `call-arguments-limit`. One can only be sure that function calls with less than `call-arguments-limit` arguments work in a given implementation of Common Lisp.

Thus for list processing with unbounded length lists one should not depend on features like `apply` or `multiple-value-call`.

**Using Multiple Values**

Common Lisp supports multiple values as a kind of optimization. It allows one to return multiple values without the need to construct a data structure for it.

Generally functions only receive single values per argument.

Everything concerned with multiple values is done via operators: `values` returns values, `multiple-value-bind` receives values and binds them to variables, ... Then there is `multiple-value-call`, `values-list`, `multiple-values-limit`, `multiple-value-list`, `multiple-value-setq`, `(setf (values ...) ...)`, `multiple-value-prog1`, `nth-value`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think values would be treated differently from normal arguments so I thought mapcar would just take each value as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is transpose a matrix as a list of lists. A standard way of doing this in Common Lisp is with the following function:

```
CL-USER> (defun transpose (list)
           (apply #'mapcar #'list list))
TRANSPOSE
CL-USER> (transpose '((3 4 2 4) (2 5 6 9) (1 -2 8 10)))
((3 2 1) (4 5 -2) (2 6 8) (4 9 10))
```

What `values-list` does is to return all the elements of a list as different result values, in order:

```
CL-USER> (values-list '((3 4 2 4) (2 5 6 9) (1 -2 8 10)))
(3 4 2 4)
(2 5 6 9)
(1 -2 8 10)
```

So your function takes the main value returned (the first list) and applies `list` to all its elements.

Note how the `transpose` function works when applied to a list argument like `'((3 4 2 4) (2 5 6 9) (1 -2 8 10))`: it “transforms” (in some sense) the call in something like:

```
(mapcar #'list '(3 4 2 4) '(2 5 6 9) '(1 -2 8 10))
```

In fact if you call directly this form it will produce the correct result:

```
CL-USER> (mapcar #'list '(3 4 2 4) '(2 5 6 9) '(1 -2 8 10)) 
((3 2 1) (4 5 -2) (2 6 8) (4 9 10))
```